# Dell XPS 13 extremely slow after update to 20.04 from 19.10

Tags: dell, performance, xps

I updated to 20.04 from 19.10 with no problem. However, the interface is very slow. Keys are very sticky at times, even if the only app running is a terminal. Mouse actions (even just pointing in a terminal) take sometimes up to 10 seconds to complete. I tried disabling networking and bluetooth to see if they were causing problems, but to no avail. It seems there is a different cause. The only thing I noticed is that, when running "top" in the terminal, "gnome-shell" is (about half the time) using almost 100% of the CPU.

This decrease in performance is really annoying, as 19.10 was working flawlessly and extremely fast. Anyone able to help, please?

The output from `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` is:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 dd dd 4096 Nov 17 10:04 .
drwx------ 4 dd dd 4096 May  3 14:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 dd dd 4096 Apr 30 12:43 extensions@abteil.org
drwxr-xr-x 3 dd dd 4096 Nov 17 09:56 hibernate-status@dromi
drwxr-xr-x 4 dd dd 4096 Nov 17 10:04 scroll-workspaces@gfxmonk.net
drwxr-xr-x 4 dd dd 4096 Nov 17 09:53 suspend-button@laserb
drwxr-xr-x 5 dd dd 4096 Apr 30 12:43 workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com
```

The output from the other command, `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` is:

```
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Nov 13 18:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

I disabled extensions in the Tweaks app and things seem to have gotten better, but not quite there yet. I still see the CPU percentage for `gnome-shell` in `top` jumping to around 90% every now and then.

Comment: You've got a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Disable ALL GNOME Shell extensions at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and restart GNOME Shell, or log out/in, and see if top shows GS at less than 3%.

Comment: @heynnema Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as I thought, you have a GNOME Shell problem.

You have (way too) many extensions installed, many of which overlap the functionality of the others. Some are installed in the wrong place... probably installed as part of an installed GNOME Shell extensions "pack".

Really, the best thing to do is delete them all, really, and/or only keep the few that you can't live without. Move/delete all of the "gcampax" ones in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` (you should only have the three non-gcampax extensions there), and leave any personal favorites in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Extensions that should stay in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`...

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:11 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ to delete them, or use Gnome Tweaks.

GNOME Shell should average less than 3% CPU when viewed in `top`. Spikes may be normal.

**Update #1:**

After cleaning up the extensions, GNOME Shell was still using too much CPU %. We created a new TEMP user, logged in there, viewed `top`, and GNOME Shell was well in line with 3% or less CPU % that I quoted. We'll troubleshoot the primary account tomorrow.

**Update #2:**

After moving around the .cache, .local, and .config folders, it was a cloud service called MegaSync. It has icon overlays in Linux/Nautilus (a rarity) but it seems to not work well with the current distribution. If I just turn that off, things work great.

Comment: How do I delete them? Not sure about that.

Comment: @Vox Answer updated for your question.

Comment: Either way, I can only delete a few. Just those with the red "X". Most don't have that option.

Comment: @Vox that's probably the ones in /usr. You may have to manually delete those folder with something like `sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax*`, then restart GNOME Shell with alt+f2, r, enter.

Comment: I marked the answer as being useful. There's still some obvious lag though even after deleting all those extensions. There's something else involved apparently. If I mark as solved, I'm not sure how I can follow up -?

Comment: @Vox What's the average GNOME Shell CPU % when viewed in `top`? Show me a screenshot of `top`. There my be other things causing additional lags. Use `iotop` and `iftop` to narrow down other sources.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107562/discussion-between-vox-and-heynnema).

Comment: I have the same issue @Vox. But I have almost no gnome extension on mine computer. 19 release was very fast and 20 update was quite ok (even if the mouse accuracy is becoming very shitty). But it is like over time, the computer become slower and slower. Since few days I need 2/3 seconds to switch application ! Did you find a solution ? I will perhaps try to clean everything a do a new clean 19 release installation.

Comment: @ArthurLambert Please start a new question with details about your problem.